# Como exibir consulta sqlite async dentro de um Widget em Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Bom dia!

Tenho um aplicativo com sqlite. A ideia é ele pegar o valor inserido pelo usuário e exibir na homepage através de soma. Consigo exibir corretamente o valor pelo console do android studio, porém não consigo exibir o valor em uma widget da ui.

como posso fazer isto?

**Pagina1.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:king_app/pages/inserir_receita.dart';

import 'estrutura/Database.dart';

    class Pagina1 extends StatelessWidget {
      final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
      int value;

      void _query() async {
        var db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
        // raw query
        var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos');
        int value = result[0]["SUM(valor)"];
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        _query();
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Página Inicial",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
            ),),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF11c76f),
            elevation: 0,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: (){},
              )
            ],
          ),
    
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 123,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF11c76f)
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Text("R\$: $value",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35,
                        color: Colors.white
                      ),),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                      child: Text('Saldo atual',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.white
                      ),),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => InserirReceita(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF11c76f),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Quero exibir o valor que é retornado na função _query no body como text.

Exatamente aqui:

```
child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Text("R\$: $value",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35,
                        color: Colors.white
                      ),),
                    ),
```

Como devo fazer? no $value era para retornar um valor porem só recebo null, vou deixar o restante do meu code abaixo que faz a conexão com sqlite.

**Database.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {

  static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;

  static final table = 'lancamentos';

  static final colunaId = '_id';
  static final colunaValor = 'valor';
  static final colunaData = 'data';
  static final colunaDescri = 'descri';
  static final colunaTipo = 'tipo';

  // make this a singleton class
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  // only have a single app-wide reference to the database
  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
  _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
    return await openDatabase(path,
        version: _databaseVersion,
        onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  // SQL code to create the database table
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $colunaId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $colunaValor NUMERIC,
            $colunaData TEXT,
            $colunaTipo TEXT,
            $colunaDescri TEXT
          )
          ''');
  }

  // Helper methods

  // Inserts a row in the database where each key in the Map is a column name
  // and the value is the column value. The return value is the id of the
  // inserted row.
  Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(table, row);
  }

  // All of the rows are returned as a list of maps, where each map is
  // a key-value list of columns.
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRows() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(table);
  }

  // All of the methods (insert, query, update, delete) can also be done using
  // raw SQL commands. This method uses a raw query to give the row count.
  Future<int> queryRowCount() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table'));
  }

  // We are assuming here that the id column in the map is set. The other
  // column values will be used to update the row.
  Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    int id = row[colunaId];
    return await db.update(table, row, where: '$colunaId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  // Deletes the row specified by the id. The number of affected rows is
  // returned. This should be 1 as long as the row exists.
  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(table, where: '$colunaId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O valor do value está nulo pois você não está trabalhando corretamente de forma assíncrona em seu código.

Seu método `_query()` é assíncrono.
Você está chamando ele no `build()`, ao ser executado e chegar exatamente nesta linha `await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos');`, ele já irá retornar um `Future<void>` e o `build()` continuará a execução, nesse momento seu `int value` estará nulo.

O primeiro erro é chamar o `_query()` no `build()`, toda vez que ele executar para atualizar a árvore de widgets, você irá fazer a mesma consulta no banco de dados. Então você pode mudar seu widget para `StatefulWidget` e realizar essa chamada no método `initState()`.

Porém, como você quer imprimir o valor na tela assim que ele for pego do banco de forma **assíncrona**, recomendo a utilização do widget [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). Ele irá aguardar uma requisição assíncrona e se atualizar quando a mesma for concluída.

Ao invés de:

```dart
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
  child: Text("R\$: $value",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 35,
    color: Colors.white
  ),),
),
```

Seria:

```dart
Future<int> _query() async {
  var db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
  var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos');
  return result[0]["SUM(valor)"];
}

FutureBuilder<int>(
  future: _query(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
    final state = snapshot.connectionState;
    final value = 'Carregando..';

    if(state == ConnectionState.done) {
      if(snapshot.hasError) {
        value = 'Erro..';
      } else {
        value = snapshot.data;
      }
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
      child: Text("R\$: $value",
        style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 35,
        color: Colors.white
      ),),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou